# Android deep link of redirected url

Tags: android

1. My app is configured to handle deep link "xyz"
2. Then there is a link "abc" which redirects to "xyz" with http 302
3. if "abc" is opened with chrome then chrome redirects it to "xyz" and then open my app
4. But if "abc" is opened in Gmail then Gmail does redirects it to "xyz" but it does NOT open my app.
5. I know in Gmail that if user goes to options -> open with chrome -> that will lead to behavior (3)
6. But is there any solution, which can let Gmail open my app after redirection of a url?

Comment: hi @dalvinder-singh did you find a fix for this ?

Comment: I have the exact same issue, did you find a fix or a workaround?

Comment: I know it has been a while, but did you ever find a fix for this?

Answer (score -2):

try this in your manifest, and **use full url(like: http://www.example.com/dl/appname?page=1&item=1) instead of short-cut urls**  gmail is not supporting shortcut url's since it has its own webview..

```
<intent-filter 
    android:autoVerify="true" 
    tools:node="merge">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data
        android:host="ur_host" // www.example.com/
        android:pathPrefix="any_prefix" // /dl/appname
        android:scheme="https or http"/> //http
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:scheme="urScheme"/> //example
</intent-filter>
```